# SQL запрос сгруппировать и взять уникальные значения

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица

```
Number  Item
------------
202     Book
202     Cartoon
202     Book
207     Book
205     Elephant
207     Elephant
208     Book
209     Biggy
209     Smoke
203     Smoke
```

Нужно сгруппировать по number и вывести уникальные item для него

```
202 Book Cartoon
207 Book Elephant
205 Elephant
208 Book
209 Biggy Smoke
203 Smoke
```

Comment: может быть вы имели в виду `distinct` а не уникальные?

Comment: Его и имел в виду :) 
Разве это не одно и то же?

Comment: Для mysql используйте функцию group_concat, для других СУБД задача достаточно нетривиальная. Укажите СУБД

Comment: @Mike, так указана же уже - mysql, но разве group_concat не вернет Book несколько раз для 202? А ведь надо только один раз

Comment: @BOPOH Станно, не заметил mysql, совсем непонятно куда смотрю ... не, все норм будет

Comment: @Mike, в oracle list_agg, вроде и в pg сработает. Проблемы только в sql server. Там есть pivot; двойной pivot; for xml path(''); рекурсия. А ещё можно на clr написать свою агрегатную функцию. Я такую писал, обозвал concat_str, distinct в ней работал:)

Comment: @pegoopik При рабочих оконных функциях с заданием размеров окна (preceding 1 and current) ее можно и эмулировать, хотя удаление дублей громоздко выйдет. У меня на Oracle 8i (в котором оконных и listagg в частности) вообще не было, делал через пакетную функцию запоминавшую в пакетной переменной

Comment: @pegoopik И в listagg distinct кстати нет, вот эмулируют http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510870/listagg-in-oracle-to-return-distinct-values  громоздко выходит

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select Number, group_concat(distinct Item separator ' ')
  from table
 group by Number
```

Comment: я че-то не подумал, что distinct можно в group_concat запихать

Comment: Спасибо. Прекрасно подошло.

Comment: Есть ли возможность получать разделенные значения Item? 
Впоследствии в массиве для 207 лежит "Book Elephant", а нужно "Book" и "Elephant" .

Comment: В separator задается разделитель полей. причем, по умолчанию, если `separator ' '` вообще убрать - они будут через запятую. Так же можно задать вообще любой разделитель

Comment: Или вы имеете ввиду, что бы они в php попадали в разные элементы массива - тогда нет, это невозможно, поле приходит одно вы его можете превратить в массив `explode`.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Да, только php. SQL до начала выполнения запроса должен знать сколько колонок выдаст результат, он физически не может динамически менять кол-во колонок

Comment: В  MySql есть ещё интересный вариант с накоплением в переменную. Для данной задачи выглядеть будет конечно глупо, а вот с эмулировать что-то по сложнее можно. Практически аналог рекурсии получается.