# Как объединить данные, отличающиеся одним полем?

Tags: mysql, sql

Получаю данные со множеством столбцов (`select`), которые отличаются лишь одним полем img. В итоге создаются много дублей.

Как объединить поле img?

Просто нужно получить объединенные данные img.

Сейчас выглядит выборка так:

- поля с одинаковыми значениями
- img одно

  ---
- поля с одинаковыми значениями
- img другое

Потом поля уже отличаются, но проблема создания дублей, естественно сохраняется.

Структура таблиц:

```
`product` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=400005659 ;

`product_img` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `parent` (`parent`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=143077 ;
```

Пишу запрос вида:

```
SELECT product.url, product.name, product_img.name as product_img_name 
FROM product 
JOIN product_img 
ON product_img.parent=product.parent
```

Comment: подробнее опишите проблему. покажите структуру таблиц, входные данные и желаемый результат. Укажите в какой момент вам это надо делать в запросе select, или может при вставке новых записей или обновить существующую таблицу. И обязательно укажите какую именно базу данных вы используете, потому как запросы и подходы к решению проблемы могут кардинально отличаться на разных СУБД

Comment: Обновил, так должно быть понятнее.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov "должно быть понятнее" - ненамного. Вы внимательно прочитали комментарий выше?

Comment: Надо понять почему так происходит. как оно происходит в реальном мире то, на основе чего получены данные. если все поля одинаковые кроме img, может надо класть эти поля в одну таблицу, назначать им id, а список img к этой записи хранить в другой таблице.

Comment: Обновил шапку вопроса.

Comment: Так, структура ясна и она правильная с виду. Запрос действительно выберет несколько записей у которых разное только поле img. Остался вопрос что вы хотите получить в результате запроса, что вы понимаете под "объединить поле img", если собрать через запятую, то  вам нужен group_concat http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491062/

Comment: Да, group_concat - именно то, что было нужно! Огромное спасибо!